# How does everyone know they have to get to Toman Head?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In The Great Hunt, several characters just know where to go - Toman Head, including Fain, Verin and Rand.

I can see why Rand went to Toman Head because the message Fain left. I think Verin chose to go there because she would like to see the prophecy becoming true. But why did Fain chose Toman Head? He had no reason to go there except to see a bunch of Seanchan, whom he had never met.

Was he trying to fulfill the Dragon prophecy too?

Answer (score 6):

The [wot db](http://www.wotdb.com) has this answer regarding Fain in an interview from Robert Jordan:

> **In The Great Hunt, who wrote the Dark Prophecy on the dungeon wall in Fal Dara? And why, after Ingtar released Padan Fain from the
>   dungeon, did Fain decide to go to Toman Head? We know he was rebelling
>   against Ishamael's orders (he was supposed to follow the Myrddraal to
>   Shayol Ghul) but why did Fain go to Cairhien and then to Toman Head?**
>
> A Myrddraal wrote the Dark Prophecy on orders, as a threat. I might
>   want to use some of the reasons, so the rest on that is RAFO. Fain
>   (now amalgamated with Mordeth) was seeking his own power base,
>   something he would try again with Pedron Niall and Toram Riatin. He
>   wanted enough power to be able to kill Rand, Mat and Perrin, though
>   most especially Rand, and to protect himself against agents of the
>   Shadow. Because of Darkfriend reports, the Myrddraal who wrote the
>   prophecy already knew who the strangers on Toman Head were, or claimed
>   to be: Artur Hawkwing's armies returned to reclaim the lands stolen
>   from Hawkwing's heirs. He knew that they collared women who could
>   channel, which appealed to Fain/Mordeth, since one disliked Aes Sedai
>   at best and the other purely hated them. The Myrddraal didn't simply
>   give this up to Fain, you understand. Fain is one of the few people
>   who could successfully torture information out of one of the Eyeless.
>   As for why he went to Cairhien first, he knew the location of the
>   Waygate there (along with several others and how to read the guidings
>   in the Ways, this last from Mordeth) and preferred to use the Ways
>   rather than make the longer cross-country journey from Fal Dara to
>   Toman Head.

*([Source](http://www.wotdb.com/interviews/question/229): TOR Questions of the Week, February 2005 to July 2005)*

Comment: I've always thought there was a problem with this explanation. Is he saying that Ingtar showed up to release Fain with a Fade, and Fain took the time to torture the Fade before leaving?  He has to find out about Toman Head before leaving because he leaves the message in the cell.

Comment: I agree, the time scale is slightly wonkey.

Comment: @TimK I think when he staked the Myrddraal in the village may have been when he got the information.